# Add computed column to temporary table Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, calculated-columns, temp-tables

I want to add a computed column to a global temporary table in Oracle.
For the simple tables the request works well.

```
alter table ma_table add ma_column as (column1*column2);
```

But for the temporary ones it refuses the use of `as`.
Is there a way to add a new computed column to the temporary table in Oracle?

Comment: The error message is pretty emphatic. `ORA-54010: expression column is not supported for a temporary table`. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: it's the project constraint,  actually the "alter table ma_table add ma_column;" works well when the "as" is there the request is rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty emphatic. `ORA-54010: expression column is not supported for a temporary table.`

> the "alter table ma_table add ma_column;" works well when the "as" is there the request is rejected.

The `AS` is the necessary bit of syntax for creating virtual columns. But's not the syntax it's the action. The [documentation is quite clear](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_7002.htm#SQLRF01402) on this:

> "You can create virtual columns only in relational heap tables. Virtual columns are not supported for index-organized, external, object, cluster, or temporary tables."

In this case the limitation of the platform trumps your project requirement.

Comment: Okey thanks, i found a way to do that, i have to create a script that execute an update request for every insert request. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I just found how to do it, 
I added the column with the alter request

```
alter table ma_table add ma_column [type];
```

And after that creating a script that execute an update request when the insert request is performed

```
update ma_table set ma_column=(colonne1*colonne2);
```